# Memory and otimization problems in JSTOR's XML big loop

Tags: r, xml, performance, loops, jstor

I'm having memory and otimization problems when loping over 200,000 documents of JSTOR's data for research. The documents are in xml format. More information can be found here: https://www.jstor.org/dfr/.

In the first step of the code I transform a xml file into a tidy dataframe in the following manner:

```r
    Transform <- function (x)
    {
        a <- xmlParse (x)
        aTop <- xmlRoot (a)

        Journal <- xmlValue(aTop[["front"]][["journal-meta"]][["journal-title group"]][["journal-title"]])
        Publisher <- xmlValue (aTop[["front"]][["journal-meta"]][["publisher"]][["publisher-name"]])
        Title <- xmlValue (aTop[["front"]][["article-meta"]][["title-group"]][["article-title"]])
        Year <- as.integer(xmlValue(aTop[["front"]][["article-meta"]][["pub-date"]][["year"]]))
        Abstract <- xmlValue(aTop[["front"]][["article-meta"]][["abstract"]])
        Language <- xmlValue(aTop[["front"]][["article-meta"]][["custom-meta-group"]][["custom-meta"]][["meta-value"]])

        df <- data.frame (Journal, Publisher, Title, Year, Abstract, Language, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    df
    }
```

In the sequence, I use this first function to transform a series of xml files into a single dataframe:

```r
    TransformFiles <- function (pathFiles)
    {

        files <- list.files(pathFiles, "*.xml")
        i = 2
        df2 <- Transform (paste(pathFiles, files[i], sep="/", collapse=""))
        while (i<=length(files)) 
        { 
            df <- Transform (paste(pathFiles, files[i], sep="/", collapse=""))
            df2[i,] <- df

            i <- i + 1
        }

    data.frame(df2)
    }
```

When I have more than 100000 files it takes several hours to run. In case with 200000 it eventually breaks or gets to slow over time. Even in small sets, it can be noticed that it runs slower over time. Is there something I'm doing worong? Could I do something to otimize the code? I've already tried rbind and bind-rows instead of allocating the values directly using df2[i,] <- df.

Comment: Are you running out of RAM? Have you tried [profiling](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html) your code so you see what actually is taking up time? Can you divide the problem into smaller tasks that you can then merge at the end? In general growing a data.frame one row at a time is very inefficient.

Comment: Normally the problem is time, but I have already run out of RAM once or twice. I have not tried profiling. I will do that. As for smaller tasks, not sure how to do that.

Comment: See whether you can run in chunks. 1000-2000 will be a good number. Eventually there will be two bind rows. One for the chunk and later for the chunks.

Comment: You might also use the package `jstor`: https://ropensci.github.io/jstor The package is optimized to make the import as smooth and fast as possible. Disclaimer: I am the author of the package.

Comment: What is `Transformar`? You only show `Transform`. Also, please show *I've already tried rbind and bind-rows*. It is unclear how warnings are not raised with `df2[i,] <- df` as both can have different lengths.

Comment: I'm sorry, Transformar is Transform in portuguese, I missed this part of the code when I was translating to post the question. I'll edit it. I believe they canot have different sizes by they way I have defined the functions.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for letting me know about your project. This function is part of a project of mine about a package for JSTOR data as well: https://github.com/arthurbnetto/tidyJSTOR

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the growth of objects in a loop with your assignment `df2[i,] <- df` (which by the way only works if *df* is one-row) and avoid the bookkeeping required of `while` with iterator, `i`.

Instead, consider building a list of data frames with `lapply` that you can then `rbind` together in one call outside of loop.

```
TransformFiles <- function (pathFiles)
    {
        files <- list.files(pathFiles, "*.xml", full.names = TRUE)
        df_list <- lapply(files, Transform)

        final_df <- do.call(rbind, unname(df_list))

        # ALTERNATIVES FOR POSSIBLE PERFORMANCE:

        # final_df <- data.table::rbindlist(df_list)
        # final_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)
        # final_df <- plyr::rbind.fill(df_list)
    }
```

Comment: thank you. I normally opt for loops instead of apply. I believe I should do the other way around.

Comment: Is there a way to keep track of the code with lapply? something like printing the percentage of files transformed...

Comment: You can extend the function in `lapply` with anonymous or defined function: `lapply(files, function(f) { df <- Transform(f) ...other lines... return(df) })`. By the way, did solution help?